# В чем причина остановки бота и невызова второй функции?

Tags: python, бот, telegram

Бот останавливается после выполнения первой функции и не вызывает вторую.

В чем причина?

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def mess_data(message: types.Message):
    if not db.user_exists(message.from_user.id):
        db.add_user(message.from_user.id, message.from_user.first_name)

@dp.message_handler()
async def mess_handler(message: types.Message):
    text = message.text.lower()
   
    if str(message.from_user.id) != cfg.ADMIN_ID:
        for word in cfg.WORDS:
            if word in text:
                await message.delete()
```

Подумал, что это из-за идентичных декораторов, т.е. после обработки одного и того же события  первой функцией. Но аналогично происходит при объединении функций под один декоратор:

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def mess_data(message: types.Message):
    if not db.user_exists(message.from_user.id):
        db.add_user(message.from_user.id, message.from_user.first_name)

async def mess_handler(message: types.Message):
    text = message.text.lower()
    if str(message.from_user.id) != cfg.ADMIN_ID:
        for word in cfg.WORDS:
            if word in text:
                await message.delete()
```

После добавления в код третьей функции, вторая игнорируется:

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def check_database(message: types.Message):
    if not db.user_exists(message.from_user.id):
        db.add_user(message.from_user.id, message.from_user.first_name)
        await check_bans(message)
        await mess_handler(message)
 
async def check_bans(message: types.Message):
    if db.user_bans(message.from_user.id):
        await message.delete()            
 
async def mess_handler(message: types.Message):
    text = message.text.lower()
    if str(message.from_user.id) != cfg.ADMIN_ID:
        for word in cfg.WORDS:
            if word in text:
                await message.delete()
```

Comment: "объединении функций под один декоратор" - это не объединение под один декоратор, вы просто убрали декоратор у второй функции. Декоратор всегда относится только к одной функции.

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю логику, декоратор message_handler задает функцию, которая будет вызываться при получении ботом сообщения. То что вы этот декоратор навесили на две функции не обязательно означает, что обе функции будут вызваны (нужно смотреть документацию, может так, может нет, но видимо нет). Проще всего поправить просто добавив вызов второй функции в конце первой: `await mess_handler(message)`

Comment: Да, все заработало! Спасибо!)

Comment: Но, после добавления третьей функции, возникла очередная проблема. 
В обеих таблицах users и bans есть запись одного и того же пользователя.
Первая функция работает правильно, в users добавляется запись, но затем управление перепрыгивает в третью функцию и она тоже работает правильно.
Но вторая не работает, комментарии пользователя из таблицы bans игнорируются и не удаляются.
При запуске в PyCharm код работает без ошибок. Что именно нужно поправить в коде, в чем ошибка?